# html table rowspan not working correct in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

It is the expected result and working fine in chrome.

[image]

But It broke in safari

[image]

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/evpb3zLa/

```
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">6</td>
      <td rowspan="6">6</td>
      <td rowspan="2">2</td>
      <td rowspan="3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">2</td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't found any solution on safari rowspan problem, but ended up using nested tables. That works like a charm xD.

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">6</td>
      <td rowspan="6">6</td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <table class="sub-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>fixed-1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>fixed-2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>fixed-3</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```